# Ruby on Rails - Best practice / method for loading side column content/blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, helper, instance-variables

I am developing a community / news article website where there is a side column with different "blocks" on nearly all pages. In these blocks is "Recent Articles (showing five most recent articles)," "Recent Blogs," "Recent Comments," you get the drift.

When I started out building the application, I wasn't real sure where to put the controller code (say, to call @recent_articles = Article.where...etc). I didn't think it could go into the Articles controller, because it's not always the Articles controller being called. So I thought it would work best in the application controller, as most content on the site would be calling this. I put "@recent_content" into the application controller, did a :before_filter to load it.

You might see the flaw in this. As I'm getting better with Rails, I went back to refactor as the site was loading horribly and sure enough, all my logic in the application controller defined by before_filter was being loaded on *every* action, no matter if it was needed or not. (The site sped up dramatically when I cleaned house on the application controller).

My mistake is realized, but I still need to define the instance variables for @recent_articles, @recent_blogs, etc *somewhere,* so they load up only when needed. Granted I'll be eventually caching the site content when it goes into production, but I want to be a good Rails programmer here.

So here is my question...exactly how would you handle this situation and where would you put the logic? I can think of two ways, not sure which one is better...

The first way...I took a look at a project from another Rails developer and I noticed he was doing odd things like this by creating files in the /lib folder. For example, defining a method for page meta tags or active menu states. I honestly haven't messed with the /lib folder before, figuring most of my stuff should stay in the /app folder.

The second way...seems to me like helpers might seem the way to go. Maybe I could define a "recent_articles" helper, call my @recent_articles instance variable in there, then render and pass the results to a view file in my shared folder.

Overall, which one of these ways is the better way to go, either from a performance or best-practices viewpoint? Or is there a better way of doing this that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there are many models that can call a particular method, i would probably use a module. I think that is what you are talking about in your first idea, since /lib is where modules are placed.

You can use helpers as well, but it's a good idea to keep logic out of helpers, only in models if possible. Helpers should be just used as a way to present data, they are part of views. If logic is added, then something is wrong :)

Make sure that you do not have logic in your controllers as well. I would be doing the same things in the beginning, but it's really a bad idea. Instead, put everything in your models, or maybe a module if they seem to be used by many other models.

Hope that helps you a bit :)

Comment: Ah, so those are modules in the lib folder I see. Looks like I'm going to have to read up on those...seems to be the route I need to go. Thank you much.